# Multi Tenant Authentication using Cognito - identify tenant user pool wthout tenant specific domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

We are building a multi-tenant application where each tenant has a separate user pool. There will be one central website for users to visit and login as their tenant. I am having trouble figuring out how we can identify what tenant a user belongs to (for displaying login page). There were several approaches on the internet where separate custom domains was cited as a solution but I somehow do not want that.

1. Is there any way we can determine tenant by just asking the user their email id?
2. If yes, will this inhibit the user from having same email id in different tenant user pools?
3. Will we need a db to maintain mapping of all users to their user pool id? Will this work in case where a user pool uses SSO?

Thanks in advance for the answers!